# Is there any way to write php code and make it usable with same web-app which is in j2ee

Tags: php, eclipse, web-applications, jakarta-ee

I am using Eclipse to develop a website in html, css, js, ajax for client and jsp, servlets in the server side, using mysql. I want to write some modules in php. Is it possible to integrate php code in the architecture and run on tomcat ?

Comment: Facebook has HipHop, which translates your PHP code into C++...maybe you can embed it into a Java application, i'm not quite sure.
https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Quercus](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/) or maybe create a bridge (effectively messaging) between a server running your PHP code and the Java application.  I'd consider carefully if this is the best way to architect your application, or whether the php modules should be rewritten for Java.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, look at PHP/Java Bridge http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/

There is also a PHP runtime written in Java, but I don't remember the name at the moment.